# How to Get The Default Schema Name for The Current Database User

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

How to get the schema name for the current login user stated in the connection string?

I need to get the schema name because the WebSecurity.InitializeSimpleMembership creates tables with the default schema of the current login user. I need to map my custom UserProfile entity to the created simple membership's user profile. I prefer not to recreates the simple membership POCO. I only want to assign the default schema of my custom UserProfile entity to match the simple membership default schema.

Comment: Not sure I know what you ask, but `select schema_name()` gives the default schema name, from a query.

Answer (score 2):

You can try as shown below.This is just a standard code snippet where you can get the schema details of the connection string.

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{

    //retrieve object model
    ObjectContext objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;

    //retrieve name types
    var nameTypes = objContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace);

    //set a connection String 
    var connectionString = objContext.Connection.ConnectionString;
    var connection = new EntityConnection(connectionString);
    var workspace = connection.GetMetadataWorkspace();

    var entitySets = workspace.GetItems<EntityContainer>(DataSpace.SSpace).First().BaseEntitySets;

    for (int i = 0; i < nameTypes.Count; i++)
    {
        Type type = Type.GetType(nameTypes[i].FullName);
        string schema = entitySets[type.Name].MetadataProperties["Schema"].Value.ToString();   
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this give DEFAULT Schema? Wouldn't it give you the schema of LAST BaseEntitySet in the iteration?

Comment: he will.B'cos of this : `var connectionString = objContext.Connection.ConnectionString;`.If he sends the correct `connection string` then the result is correct. @sachin

Comment: Please add `using` directives to your code, because finding correct `using` directives is nontrivial (there are alternatives which define every symbol used but don't work together)

Answer (score 1):

I use `select schema_name()` this will give me the default schema for the user stated in the connection string. Then use the result to set the entity schema in its model builder.